# if ajax function is successful display an alert

Tags: ajax, jsp, lightbox

I have a jsp named home.jsp. On click of "activate now" button in this jsp, a lightbox is being displayed.

This lightbox has 2 buttons "activate" and "remove".

When I click on "activate" button, a service is being activated. On successful activation, page is reloaded and home.jsp is displayed.

Now i want to display an alert when this happens. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your home.jsp page should queue a JavaScript snippet that runs immediately after the page gets loaded (and once it's activated). I recommend using jQuery which will make this a lot easier. Here is a dirty example:

```
<html>
<head>
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery().ready(window,function(){
           alert("your account is activated");
       });
   </script>
   ...
</head>
<body>
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

But home.jsp also has "remove" button. 
This also works in the same way as "activate now" button.
On successful removal home.jsp page is reloaded.

But i want to display alert only when "activate now" button is clicked.

Comment: Note: jsp used for displaying "activate" lightbox is confirmActivation.jsp and jsp used for displaying "remove" lightbox is confirmRemoval.jsp

Comment: You must dynamically add the javascript to the jsp page. That way you can control when the message get's displayed.

Comment: Could u pls tell me how to add script dynamically